# Space being left where div is located in html but overlay position is not

Tags: html, css, image, overlay

Just wondering how to get rid of the space above the slider. The space is exactly equal to how much height there is to the image. Please help! I thought overflow hidden would help but that doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

HTML

```
<div class="overlayImage"></div>
<div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
<img src="images/collin-banner.jpg" data-thumb="Images/Slider/christmas_concert_slider.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/toystory.jpg" data-thumb="Images/Slider/join-the-chorus.jpg" alt="" />                                 
<img src="images/up.jpg" data-thumb="Images/Slider/book-the-chorus.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/walle.jpg" data-thumb="Images/Slider/ways-you-can-give.jpg" alt="" />                              
</div><!-- end slider --->                      
</div><!--- End slider-wrapper theme-default--->
```

CSS:

```
.overlayImage {
    z-index: 999;
    background-image: url(../images/logo-overlay.png);
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 484px 185px;
    width: 484px;
    height: 185px;
    top: 320px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/46tUg/)

```
.overlayImage {
    z-index: 999;
    background-image: url(../images/logo-overlay.png);
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute; //changed
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-size: 484px 185px;
    width: 484px;
    height: 185px;
    top: 0px;  //changed 
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Go through this link [**CSS POSITION PROPERTY**](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp) to know more

Comment: This is close. The only issue is now if I use the Top and Left attributes to center, it wont be center on all resolution sizes. How Do I get it to be centered no matter what without that space on the top showing up?